# Displaying Elements from a Linked List

Tags: c++, tree, linked-list

I'm working on a program where a user enters random numbers, the program takes those numbers and puts them into a tree, and then into a linked list. The user is then asked to enter two boundaries and the program displays all the numbers in-between the max and the min.

Eg.

```
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 2
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 3
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 4
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 5
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 6
Enter an integer or 0 to quit: 0
The values are:
2 3 4 5 6
Enter the minimum:
2
Enter the maximum:
6
The list is: 0x3f0d58

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.464 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The problem is that my program does not output the list, instead it outputs 0x3f0d58.

The function that does the outputing is

```
void createlist()  //creates linked list
{
    linkednode *current;
    linkednode *begin;
    current=new linkednode;
    current->data=data[0];
    current->next=NULL;
    begin=current;
    for (int count=1; count<(int)data.size(); count++)
    {
        current=appendlist(current,data[count]);
    }
    cout<<"The list is: "<<begin<<endl;
}
```

What should I change in order to get the actual numbers to be outputted?

Comment: Firstly, you could change your question to make the code understandable

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you you pointers at all!

please have a look at :[Pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for description more specialized to C++

- A pointer must always be of the same type as the variable it's
  pointing at.
- Declaring a pointer variable does not create the type of    variable
  it points at. It creates a pointer variable.
- Though pointers are declared with an asterisk they are not always
  used with an    asterisk. The asterisk is the unary * operator.
  int *number;
- Pointers must be initialized before they can be used. Initialize a
  pointer by assigning it to a variable; the variable must be of the
  same type as the pointer.
- To assign a pointer to a variable, use an ampersand with the
  variable's name.

  m_address = &memory;
- To assign a pointer to an array, do not use the ampersand

  s_address= string;

  and NOT  s_address= &string; (this works too but not done conventionally)
- However to assign a pointer to an array "element", use the ampersand:

  element = &string[2];
- If you are using pointers with a struct, you will need to use the
  pointer structure notation, ->

  **Without an asterisk, an initialized pointer holds a memory address.
  With an asterisk, an initialized pointer references the value stored
  at its address.** This is where you have gone wrong.

Comment: That's not how you use answers at all! Please have a look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Sorry am new around here. Will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code  outputs the `begin` value. And `begin` is a pointer to the first node. `cout` does not know that it is some specific pointer, for it there is no difference whether it points to struct A or struct B. And even if it would have considered any difference, it does not know what members and how should be printed. So you have to output the values manually in the same way you add them.
Also it is better to make data a parameter to the function - it will look more coherent and you will avoid any global data.